# Save edited datatable Shiny

Tags: shiny

When the create action button is clicked, an empty and editable datatable is presented to the users. Once they have filled and edited the datatable, the data must be saved in a new dataframe. Alternatively, the edited datatable data can be extracted and used to create a new dataframe. It is preferable to use the action button to create the new dataframe.

```
fillCol(DTOutput("dtable2", height = "100%"))


data_22 <- eventReactive(input$create, {
  dat2 <<- matrix(nrow = input$DMU_Num+2, ncol = input$ind_NUM+1)
  colnames(dat2)[2:ncol(dat2)] <- paste0("Indicies ", 1:ncol(dat2))
  colnames(dat2)[1]<-"Names"
  dat2 <<- as.data.frame(dat2)
  dat2
})

callback <- c(
  "$.contextMenu({",
  "  selector: 'table th',", 
  "  trigger: 'right',",
  "  autoHide: true,",
  "  items: {",
  "    text: {",
  "      name: 'Enter column header:',", 
  "      type: 'text',", 
  "      value: ''", 
  "    }",
  "  },",
  "  events: {",
  "    show: function(opt){",
  "      $.contextMenu.setInputValues(opt, {text: opt.$trigger.text()});",
  "    },",
  "    hide: function(opt){",
  "      var $this = this;",
  "      var text = $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data()).text;",
  "      var $th = opt.$trigger;",
  "      $th.text(text);",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});" 
)

output[["dtable2"]] <- renderDT({
  datatable(
    data_22(),
    escape = T,
    editable = list(target = "cell",colnames = TRUE),
    class = 'cell-border',
    extensions = "Buttons", 
    options = list(
      dom = 'Blfrtip', 
      buttons=c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),
      br(),
      lengthMenu = list(c(10, 25, 50, -1), c(10, 25, 50, "All"))
      
    ),
    callback = JS(callback)
  )
})  

proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable2")

new_dat<- reactiveValues()
observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
  
  new_dat <<- editData(dat2, input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], proxy, rownames = TRUE)
})


renderTable(new_dat())
```

Comment: please provide a full (and minimal) app